# Stack Overflow em Português 5 anos

Tags: debate, comunidade

Acabamos de completar 5 anos de Stack Overflow em Português. Eu quero agradecer a todos que fizeram parte disto e principalmente de todos que me ensinaram alguma coisa, não só respondendo, mas qualquer participação acaba nos ensinando mesmo quando não parece. Claro, os conhecimentos técnicos que obtive são destaque em tudo isto. Espero que você tenha aproveitado também. De minha parte ainda o maior desafio é lidar com um público cada vez mais diverso e que está menos interessado em nosso modelo para consumo rápido de soluções.

Não foi uma trajetória fácil, estamos vendo novas dificuldades, mas estamos fazendo história dentro das nossas possibilidades. Tudo o que fazemos aqui ficará para sempre. A ajuda que estamos dando para muitas pessoas de alguma forma certamente estão fazendo a diferença nas suas vidas.

Precisamos lidar com essa leva de novos usuários que nos desafia a cada dia para termos mais 5 anos de sucesso.

Em anos anteriores eu já relatei a diferença que o SOpt fez em minha vida, e que ainda tem feito, então desta vez abro o espaço apenas para o seu relato sobre sua experiência aqui.

Comment: Vida longa ao StackOverflow!

Answer (score 13):

Só agradecimento a todos que fazem o SOpt acontecer, estou aqui a pouco mais de 1 ano, bastante tempo sendo um *ghost* só sugando, porém de um tempo pra cá comecei participar ativamente e além de perguntar também responder. Que venha mais 5, 10, 15 anos de SOpt, e que com o passar dos anos os usuários entendam melhor a filosofia por trás dessa plataforma.

Answer (score 11):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em 2 anos de atividade no SOPT aprendi 100x mais do que sabia ou aprendi em 10 anos de profissão. Acredito que o aprendizado é algo constante, que nunca termina, você nunca sabe tudo, e quando acha que sabe, surge algo que lhe surpreende. E essa tem sido minha experiência cotidiana no SOPT.

Tenho feito boas amizades, e isso é super gratificante porque, além de compartilhar um pouquinho do que aprendi, também aprendo muito. Já tive também muitos problemas por aqui, como esquecer a senha de acesso

Desejo muito prosperidade ao SOPT e a seus usuários, dos mais principiantes aos mais experientes, e que venham mais gerações no futuro, de moderadores e usuários.

Eu já sou um "velho" de 44 anos. Vou viver no máximo mais 30 ou 35 anos (sendo muito otimista ), se Deus permitir. Só gostaria que houvesse uma lembrança sempre dos usuários que fizeram história desde o início do site, como o Maniero, Sergio, Bacco, bfavarreto entre outros (desculpem, fiz uma lembrança rápida de nomes, não fui pesquisar).

3nf1n! 5vc3ç0 4 t0d05!!!

Answer (score 4):

**SOPT** é um lugar fantástico, com uma comunidade muito ativa e uma fonte gigantesca de conhecimento e pesquisa, diversas vezes me perdi por entre as dezenas de perguntas e respostas interessantes cheias de conteúdo que certamente nos fazem crescer como profissionais e como pessoas, por mais 5, 10, 15, 20 anos de conhecimento, pois aprender é um dom e um privilegio do ser humano.

Grande abraço a todos que contribuem com esta comunidade.